# Python multiprocessing Pool start multiple GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, import, pyqt, multiprocessing

All,
In my GUI I'm using multiprocessing to run a function. But the pool start multiple GUI.
I have read that peoples add `if __name__ == '__main__':` in their code and it seems to work.
But I don't know if this trick will work in my case, and where I have to insert this code. 
The function run_func() is launched by a button in the GUI. 
How can I block this multiple start?

I have a second question:
How can I do to unimport setup at the end of the exec?

Thanks a lot !

```
@pyqtSlot()
    def run_func():
        run="""
        import os
        import sys
        from setup import *
        print('toto')
        print('titi')
        """
        from multiprocessing import Pool   
        pool = Pool(processes=4)          
        asyncResult = pool.apply_async(exec(run),{},{}),range(1)
```

Comment: Is your GUI launched in setup.py? Is launching it not protected by `if __name__ == "__main__":`? Also, why don't you just create a regular function and call `apply_async` on that? Using `exec` the way you are is not the right way do to it.

Comment: Thank you dano. My GUI is not launched in setup.py. I have a Main which launch a QApplication which launch my QMainWindow. Then my QMainWindow launch run_func() by an QAction.I can directly lauch a function in apply_async you are right but it don't solve the multiple start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide much context for your question. Anyway I made a test removing the `from setup import *` part from the `run` string. And all run well, hence, is not a PyQT problem, is more like at some point you're executing again the module/function that runs the GUI.

**For the first question:**

I recommend you to use a debugger and set some breakpoints where the GUI is launched, then you can use the call-stack for figureout who is calling your GUI. That way yuo will know where the '**main**' code block goes, and even if it is really necessary.

As debugger use pdb with in-code breakpoints (remember you're running in multiprocess) put the line:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

where ever yuo want to set a breakpoint.

**For the second question:**

See, [How do I unload (reload) a Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I find a lot of problem and I think multiprocessing is not what i am looking for. I am looking for a way to run a script outside of my GUI. I want to run a script in a container or something like that.

Comment: Just post another question, I´m sure you will find help here.

Comment: Thank you, I posted it.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180766/run-python-script-in-a-container-in-a-gui?noredirect=1#comment37336844_24180766)