# Run python script in a container in a GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, pyqt, multiprocessing

I am looking for a way to run scripts in a container in my GUI.

The GUI generate a script and i want to run this script without effect on my GUI.
My problem is that all the imports and class in my script stay in memory after the run and generate errors in the GUI.
Is it possible to run the script, get the result and delete all consequences of the scrpt run?

I tried with multiprocessing,threading but It is not working. How can I do that? Thanks a lot!

Hi Mátyás Kuti, I just have the case with multiprocessing for now. I want to find a way to run it in a sort of container that I can delete when the script stop.

```
@pyqtSlot()
def run_func():
    run="""
    import os
    import sys
    from setup import *
    print('toto')
    print('titi')
    """
    from multiprocessing import Pool   
    pool = Pool(processes=4)          
    asyncResult = pool.apply_async(exec(run),{},{}),range(1)
```

Comment: Could you provide some code, showing _how_ you've tried using threads?

Comment: @user3393374 You should edit your question and include that sample code. It's not readable in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I will expose to you another approach. You can generate a temporary file wich contain the code you want to execute, and then use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module for excecute it with the command "python you_script.py"

The next example execute an script that prints to output all the files an directories in the working dir.

```
import os           # Common os operations.
import subprocess   # For creating child processes.
import tempfile     # For generating temporary files.

def make_temp_script(script):
    """ 
    Creates a temp file with the format *.py containing the script code.
    Returns the full path to the temp file. 
    """
    # Get the directory used for temporaries in your platform.
    temp_dir = os.environ['TEMP']
    # Create the script.
    _ , path = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix=".py", dir=temp_dir)
    fd = open(path, "w")
    fd.write(script)
    fd.close()
    return path


def execute_external_script(path):
    """
    Execute an external script.
    Returns a 2-tuple with the output and the error.
    """
    p = subprocess.Popen(["python", path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    return (out, err)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    script =  \
    """
    import os
    import sys

    print(os.listdir())
    """

    path = make_temp_script(script)
    out, err = execute_external_script(path)

    print(out)
    print(err)
```

You can try something like the example in your code:

```
@pyqtSlot()
def run_func():
    run="""
    import os
    import sys
    from setup import *
    print('toto')
    print('titi')
    """

    path = make_temp_script(run)
    result, error = execute_external_script(path)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try and let you know .

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the script into a function:

```
script = """
def func():
""" + yourScript
yourGlobals = ...
exec script in yourGlobals
yourGlobals["func"]()
```

The above code is just the general idea: you will have to fix it to indent `yourScript`. All globals created by your script will in fact be locals to `func` so will be removed after `func` returns. The imports will probably not be removed, there will continue to be an entry in the package table.

If the above is not sufficient because imports don't get purged, perhaps you can describe the error and what imports are left that cause error, may be there is another way around this.

If the script can take a long time to run then the above technique can work in a separate thread too.